# Surviving hordes 7DTD

Tags: 7-days-to-die

Since the alpha 13 and the global upgrading materials system, I was wondering, which is more rewarding regarding the time spent looting/crafting between doing your base with wood then upgrade it to iron or using clay in forge to craft wall or using cobblestone frame with cobble inside.

This 3 types of defense for the first two hordes are pretty great and enough to survive easily but which one is the better regarding the time spent gathering the resources and crafting what is needed?

I'm talking only about the main structure of the base, not about the spike or trap/mine that can be put around to help you defend your position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, I think it depends greatly on which resource you have the most of. The early hordes can probably be handled (if you are actively killing them) with just upgraded wood, but only if you can get enough wood to upgrade your wood frames to at least level 2. Later hordes will likely tear through this easily since the hordes would be much larger.

If you start mining early (ie get a decent level pickaxe as loot, perhaps) and get tons of stone, I'd recommend going the cobblestone (or cement/concrete if you find the book) route. I usually don't use cobblestone, so I'm not sure if they can be later upgraded to concrete. I did test last night that regular a concrete block can be upgraded to reinforced concrete with 10 concrete mix (no rebar frames required).

To reiterate, I really think it just makes a difference which material you have more up between wood and stone. If you're in the desert, for example, I'd choose the stone/cobblestone option. If you're in a forest with tons of trees, I'd go the wooden (upgraded wood frames) route. Just remember to upgrade either of them eventually for later hordes.

I also make a point to plant the 2 maple seeds whenever I cut down a tree (close to my base) so I don't find myself without a wood source when I really need it.

Comment: I'm actually not shot on any ressources, I have found a good fire axe and pick axe the first day, and found a concrete book already, so it is more for an efficient defense in the later point of the game that I seek to know what is beter to be done since the start and upgrading for the next hordes.